# Four infinite series involving Riemann zeta function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

Can you provide a proof for at least one of the claims given below?

It is known that $\pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n-1}{4^n} \cdot \zeta(n+1)$ where $\zeta$ denotes [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) (Vardi 1991) . Similarly we can formulate the following claims:

> **Claim 1.**
> $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{3^n} \cdot \zeta(n+1)$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrTbI1NjAwsOYqti0uzdXIszXUKU3S0dAwisvTNdTU1zCOy9PU1KpKLUnUyNM21NS05iooyswr0SjWMtSDcwIy9YsLi0o0jIHyAJpuFuc=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

> **Claim 2.**
> $$\sqrt{3} \pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^n-1}{6^n} \cdot \zeta(n+1)$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrTbI1NjAwsOYqti0uzdXIszXUKU3S0dAwjcvTNdTU1zCLy9PU1KpKLUnUyNM21NS05iooyswr0SjWMtSDczSKC4tKNIw1tQIygSoAyEwXOQ==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

> **Claim 3.**
> $$(\sqrt{2}+1) \pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{7^n-1}{8^n} \cdot \zeta(n+1)$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrTbI1NjAwsOYqti0uzdXIszXUKU3S0ahKLUnUyNM21NTU0jCPy9M11NTX0LCIy9PU1LTmKijKzCvRKNYy1INzAjK1NIoLi0o0jDRBmqwBJf0X6Q==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

> **Claim 4.**
> $$(\sqrt{3}+2) \pi=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{11^n-1}{12^n} \cdot \zeta(n+1)$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrTbI1NjAwsOYqti0uzdXIszXUKU3S0ahKLUnUyNM21NTU0jA0jMvTNdTU19AwNIrL09TUtOYqKMrMK9Eo1jLUg3MCMrU0jLSLC4tKNIxBagBKFxhB&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: I might be wrong... these can be obtained from manipulating the parametrized sums from the same wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Infinite_series . One takes certain linear combinations of sums to obtain your series, while on the RHS the polygamma functions will simplify due mirror symmetry. This is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: Even simpler is to use this generating function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Taylor_series

Comment: Nemo, I would love to see some details (it does not seem obvious or simple to me)!

Comment: It is interesting that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit (fundamental?) in the real quadratic field with discriminant 8, $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a unit (fundamental?) in the real quadratic field of discriminant 12.