# A expression for the tangent function involving $\zeta(n),n=2,3,\ldots$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

A few procrastinal computations motivated by [Four infinite series involving Riemann zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401468/four-infinite-series-involving-riemann-zeta-function) suggest the identity
$$\tan\left(\frac{\kappa-1}{\kappa+1}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\kappa^n-1}{(\kappa+1)^n}\zeta(n+1)$$
for all $\kappa>0$. (Both sides change sign when replacing $\kappa$ by $1/\kappa$. It is thus enough to consider $\kappa\geq 1$.)

I checked it on $100$ random values up to 400 digits which convinced me that it must hold.

Is there an easy explanation?

(Remark: This identity, if true, provides of course easy answers to question M0401468 mentionned above.)

(Computational remark: For high precision computation, it is perhaps best to cut the sum at some not very large value $N$ (I worked with $N=400$) and to approximate the omitted terms by summing the first few terms contributing to $\zeta(N+1),\ldots$, by considering the associated geometric progressions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was writing my answer, Dan Romik answer appeared. Mine is the same but with more detail.

We have
$$\log\Gamma(1-x)=\gamma x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\zeta(n)\frac{x^n}{n}$$
(this is known and is also an exercise in complex analysis).
Hence by differentiation
$$-\frac{\Gamma'(1-x)}{\Gamma(1-x)}-\gamma=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n) x^{n-1}$$
It follows that (I change $\kappa$ into $x$)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n-1}{(x+1)^n}\zeta(n+1)=
\frac{\Gamma'(1-\frac{1}{x+1})}{\Gamma(1-\frac{1}{x+1})}+\gamma
-\frac{\Gamma'(1-\frac{x}{x+1})}{\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{x+1})}-\gamma$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{x}{x+1})}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{x+1})}-\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{1}{x+1})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{x+1})}=\frac{\Gamma'(y)}{\Gamma(y)}-\frac{\Gamma'(1-y)}{\Gamma(1-y)}=\frac{d}{dy}\log(\Gamma(y)\Gamma(1-y))=\frac{d}{dy}\log\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi y}$$
$$=-\frac{\pi\cos\pi y}{\sin\pi y}=-\pi\cot\pi y=\pi\cot\frac{\pi x}{x+1}$$
$$=-\pi\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi x}{x+1}\Bigr)=-\pi\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1-x}{1+x}\Bigr)=\pi\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x-1}{x+1}\Bigr).$$

Comment: Thank you for this detailled answer. (I have already accepted Dan Romiks answer but you beat him for clarity.)

Comment: @RolandBacher If you think this is a better answer (I'm not going to judge either way) then you can change your accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked the details, but this should follow in a straightforward way from a [standard relation for the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) $\psi(z) = \Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$, namely
$$
\psi(z+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \zeta(n+1) z^n,
$$
together with the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)
$$
\psi(1-z)-\psi(z) = \pi \cot(\pi z).
$$
Mathematica knows about these formulas, and confirms that your identity is correct, as seen in this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for "disaccepting" your answer (which I like) but juan's answer puts all the dots on the i's.

Comment: @RolandBacher no problem.